# Discord bot made with lua, discordia does not react

Tags: lua, discord, bots

I'm trying to make a bot react to it's own message however when it tries to it gets this message:

```
/Desktop/Bot/main.lua:96: attempt to call method 'reactionAdd' (a nil value)
```

here is the script that makes the bot react to it's message

```
if message.content == "press f to pay respects" then
    if message.author.bot then
        message.reactions:reactionAdd(":seven:")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax you're looking for is `message:addReaction(":seven:")`.

Comment: now it works but it now says `2022-06-28 15:49:06 | [ERROR]   | 400 - Bad Request : PUT https://discord.com/api/v7/channels/990425554585026584/messages/991430058357051403/reactions/%3Aseven%3A/@me
` despite the ":seven:"

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `message:addReaction("emoji id")`

Comment: like i said in another comment it's not registering the id